# PHP (BASICO) Asignacion de Objeto y Clase

Tags: php, poo

tengo una consulta...

El siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

$instancia = new ClaseSencilla();

$asignada   =  $instancia;
$referencia =& $instancia;

$instancia->var = '$asignada tendrá este valor';

$instancia = null; // $instancia y $referencia son null

var_dump($instancia);
var_dump($referencia);
var_dump($asignada);
?>
```

Que produce la siguiente salida:

```
NULL
NULL
object(ClaseSencilla)#1 (1) {
   ["var"]=>
     string(27) "$asignada tendrá este valor"
}
```

> Línea nro 5: "string(27) "$asignada........."

Porque devuelve eso? 
Pregunto porque mi lógica (que seguro está errada) dice que debería devolver NULL o un error dado que en el momento en el que se le asigno el valor de `$instancia" a "$asignada`... `$asignada` no tenía ningun valor en `$var`, el valor fue asignado después ! (`$instancia->var = $asignada` tendrá....)

El ejemplo no lo probé lo saque de la documentación oficial de php:
https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php

Espero que se entienda mi consulta y que puedan sacar mis dudas!

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tenemos que:

- [La asignación (=)](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new):

> Cuando se asigna una instancia ya creada de una clase a una nueva variable, ésta última accederá a la misma instancia que el objeto que le fue asignado.

- [La asignación por referencia (=&)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatare.php)

> Las Referencias en PHP son medios de acceder al mismo contenido de una variable mediante diferentes nombres.No son como los punteros de C; por ejemplo, no se puede realizar aritmética de punteros con ellas, realmente no son direcciones de memoria, etc. Véase [¿Qué NO son las Referencias?](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.arent.php) para más información. Observe que en PHP el nombre de la variable y el contenido de la variable son cosas diferentes, por lo que el mismo contenido puede tener diferentes nombres.

Lo que quiere decir es que:

```
$asignada = $instancia; //Crea una nueva var que apunta a la instancia.
$referencia =& $instancia; //Crea una var que apunta por referencia al valor de la var $instancia.
```

Al hacer:

```
$instancia = null;
```

Lo que estamos diciendo es que el nuevo valor de `$instancia` es `null`, tan simple como eso. La variable `$asignada` sigue apuntando a la instancia.